# grafana plotting non time related data

Tags: grafana

I'd like to know if it's at all possible to plot non time related data in Grafana (which is is very good for plotting time series), besides providing single data points (even at the price of js customizations of custom flot graphs) ?

By example, plotting a pie chart or an histogram for the given time range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of Grafana does not support such kind of graph. But developer promised this in future versions.

Comment: do you know of an issue id where this is referenced ?

Comment: Yes, here is:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/568
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1054

Comment: Pie graphs are requested in that bug report ; do you think other kind of plots could be implicitely referenced by this also (ie trivial once you get pie charts) ?